# how to create/apply theme specific to domain in websphere portal 8.5

Tags: themes, websphere-portal

I should apply themes based on the domain (hostname). say for an instance, if request is from abc.com, then I need to apply abc theme. if request is from xyz.com, then i need to apply xyz theme. is there a way in Portal 8.5?

Answer (score 0):

Would abc.com and xyz.com take you to the same content/page within the portal?  I'm assuming each domain would point to different content/page or different virtual portals.  If you have different virtual portals, each vp can have a default theme configured.  If they are just pointing to different content/page, then you would can apply a theme per page.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I should have mentioned it. both domains are going to the same content/page. only difference it gonna make is that appearance based on domain. so thinking is there a way. currently we are making a condition in default.jsp based on domain loading styles. is there a better way?  if it would have been different content obviously I would have went with VP.